# How can I only display data that conforms to the requirements put in place?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, ubuntu

I have a program that takes in a csv file which stores data in this format ` Lastname,Name,YYYYMMDD` (last bit is year month day for birthday) that only accepts **only gregorian calendar years** and I want my program to display all files which corresponds to the input month (string of the name of the month).

For instance, if the input month is "May", my program should display all files that have 05 in the MM section of the birthday.

Can anyone please help explain what should I ?

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Enter csv file"
    read file
    echo "Enter month"
    read month
    cat "$file" | cut -f3 -d',' |    // this line seperates the csv file and focuses on the 3rd argument, which are the birthdays
```

Comment: You need to first convert the word _May_ into a month number (`05`). Then you need to get all lines in the file which have a `05` in the appropriate place of the timestamp. Since these are two tasks which can be treated independently, you would have to ask 2 questions, since on Stackoverflow, each question should focus on a single problem only.

Answer (score 1):

With *GNU* `date`(1) and `grep`(1), something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rp "[Enter csv file]: " file
read -rp "[Enter month]: " month

[[ -z "$file" || -z "$month" ]] && {
  printf >&2 'file and month needs an input value!\n'
  exit 1
}

[[ -e "$file" ]] || {
  printf >&2 "Cannot open \`%s' (No such file or directory)\n" "$file"
  exit 1
}

##: Add more test if needed such as if the file is
##: A regular file and not a directory and so on...
##: readable by the user and so on...
##: See help test

input_month="$(date -d "1$month" '+%m' 2>&1)" || {
  stat=$?
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "${input_month/1}"
  exit "$stat"
}

grep "$input_month" "$file" || exit
```

---

- See `help test`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an ideal job for awk

```
cat foo
Lastname,Name,20230523
foo,baz,20230117

m=May
awk -F, -vmonth=$m -f month.awk foo
Lastname,Name,20230523
```

month.awk is:

```
BEGIN {
    months["Jan"] = "01";
    months["Feb"] = "02";
    months["Mar"] = "03";
    months["Apr"] = "04";
    months["May"] = "05";
    code = months[month];
}

substr($3,5,2) ~ code {print $0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash

month=May
target_csv=my.dat

while read -r line ; do 
    d="${line##*,}"
    case "${d:4:2}" in
        01) mm=Jan ;;
        02) mm=Feb ;;
        03) mm=Mar ;;
        04) mm=Apr ;;
        05) mm=May ;;
        06) mm=Jun ;;
        07) mm=Jul ;;
        08) mm=Aug ;;
        09) mm=Sep ;;
        10) mm=Oct ;;
        11) mm=Nov ;;
        12) mm=Dec ;;
        *) echo "unknown month" && exit 1 ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$mm" == *"$month"* ]] ; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done <"$target_csv"
```

Another version of the script showing use of positional parameters and/or default values for `month` and `target_csv`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# You may pass the target month as positional parameter 
# to script execution or will default to the value May and
# You may pass the target csv file as the second positional 
# parameter or will default to the value my.dat.
# Example usage:  ./script_name May target.csv
month="${1:-May}"
target_csv="${2:-my.dat}"

while read -r line ; do 
    d="${line##*,}"
    case "${d:4:2}" in
        01) mm=Jan ;;
        02) mm=Feb ;;
        03) mm=Mar ;;
        04) mm=Apr ;;
        05) mm=May ;;
        06) mm=Jun ;;
        07) mm=Jul ;;
        08) mm=Aug ;;
        09) mm=Sep ;;
        10) mm=Oct ;;
        11) mm=Nov ;;
        12) mm=Dec ;;
        *) echo "unknown month" && exit 1 ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$mm" == *"$month"* ]] ; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done <"$target_csv"
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response, can you please explain what  d="${line##*,}" means??

Comment: It is bash parameter expansion that extracts everything after the last comma into the variable `d` from the variable `line`.

Comment: thank you, also if I want to let the user input the month and the csv file to be used, can I just do                                                                                                              
*echo "Enter a value for month"
read month
                                echo "Enter a csv file"
read file
target_csv="$file"* instead?

Comment: sorry I can't format my comment into code for some reason, the command doesnt work

Comment: There is limited formatting available in comments. You can prompt the user as you indicated, but it might be better just to pass the month and target csv files as positional parameters when executing your script.  Something like `your_scripte May target.csv` Then you can refer to the month using `$1` and the csv using `$2` inside your script.

Comment: Can you show in code what u mean, (either in comments or edited in ur response)? I'm kinda confused on how that would be possible

Comment: See the addition to answer above.  (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html)